# How can i read numbers from a file

Tags: c

at first glance this may look a dumb question but am really stuck and in a hurry....
I have a file that countain an X number of numbers stocked in a file.
I can stock the numbers in the file in this way

```
22 56 102 9 302
```

in a single ligne with a space between each number.

Or i can stock them this way in one colone

```
22 
56 
102 
9 
302
```

either way i coudln't find an easy way to retrieve those number and stock them in a table to use them later on. Because one of the problem i don't know how many digit in each number (can be only one digit or even 5) so i can't use `sscanf`.

So can anyone of you help me how to add those numbers to a table (whether the number in a single line or single colone, which ever easy). (in C language)

(really sorry if this question seems kinda dumb, but i'm really in a rush )

editt:: the number of numbers in the file han be really high

edit 2:
this what i tried to do (in case the number are in a single colonne)

```
  int i=0,k;
char buffer[500];

fd=fopen("Fdonne.txt", "r");   //fd global variable


 fgets(buffer,300, fd);
while(feof(fd) == 0)
      {
     sscanf(buffer,"%d",tb[i]); //tb already declared also
     i++;
     fgets(buffer,300, fd);
       }

for (k=0; k<(count+1); k++) // count is my X here 
    printf("%d ",tb[k]);
```

this seemed the most logical thing but, reading ligne by ligne and usse the sscanf but smh when i run the program nothing show (so there is a problem somewhere)

Comment: Your question states "in C language" but you also tagged C#. Is it one or the other? That will change the answer(s) you receive.

Comment: No need to use `fgets()` and `sscanf()`. Just use `fscanf()` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to *obtain the numbers* which you can do with a help of `string.Split` and *Linq*:

```
  int[] numbers = File
    .ReadLines(@"c:\MyFile.txt")
    .SelectMany(line => line.Split(
       new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' }, 
       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .Select(item => int.Parse(item))
    .ToArray();
```

If tiy want to store the numbers in a file:

```
 File
   .WriteAllLines(@"c:\SomeOtherFile.txt", numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextFieldParser datReader = new TextFieldParser(Application.StartupPath + @"write here your file address");
        datReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { " " });
        datReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
        string colFields = datReader.ReadToEnd();
        List<string> lineOrder = new List<string>();

        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(colFields))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lineOrder.Add(line);
            }
        }
```